# How to get media details(title, album, etc) from JavaFX Media object and add details to ObservableList?

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I have created an `ArrayList` of media file paths and i want to get details of media file like title and album info in my JavaFX application. I want to add these details in `ObservableList`. So I created an iterator which gives path of all media files. Inside iterator loop, I have created a `Media` object. To get media information from `Media` object, I have created metadata event listener. I got media information in lambda function but i can't able to use them outside of lambda function. If i add info in `ObservableList` inside event listener lambda function than many null values inserting because of meta data iteration and only one useful information is inserting.

Here is my code:

```
ObservableList<PlayListModel> playListData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Iterator<JMPPlayListItem> it = playList.getIterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    listMedia = new Media(it.next().getPath());
    PlayListModel playListItem = new PlayListModel();
    listMedia.getMetadata().addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> c)->  {
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            if ("artist".equals(c.getKey())) {
                playListItem.setArtist(c.getValueAdded().toString());
            } else if ("title".equals(c.getKey())) {
                // It prints title of song
                System.out.println(c.getValueAdded().toString());
                playListItem.setTitle(c.getValueAdded().toString());
            } else if ("album".equals(c.getKey())) {
                playListItem.setAlbum(c.getValueAdded().toString());
            }
        }
    });
    // It print null
    System.out.println(playListItem.getTitle());
    playListData.add(playListItem);
}
```

`System.out.println(c.getValueAdded().toString())` is printing title of song but outside of lambda function `System.out.println(playListItem.getTitle())` prints null. It means `playListItem` object's values isn't changing. I tried making `playListItem` final but wouldn't help. I also tried initializing `playListItem` object and `playListData.add(playListItem)` inside lambda function but it inserts title with many null title values because of event listener iteration.

I also tested with local variables but I'm not able to get values outside of listener lambda function.

Comment: The metadata of a `Media` object is not avaiable immediately. From the documentatin, "_The media information is obtained asynchronously and so not necessarily available immediately after instantiation of the class. All information should however be available if the instance has been associated with a `MediaPlayer` and that player has transitioned to `MediaPlayer.Status.READY` status_". When you go to print out the title is hasn't been set yet.

Comment: But when i print in addListener function then media information is printing. I just can't able to use these information outside addListener function.

Comment: Your listener is _observing_ the `ObservableMap` of metadata. It will be notified _when the values become available_.

Comment: I got your point now. So what is solution on such a situation?

Comment: As the `println`s are likely just for debugging, where are you trying to use the values? What is the actual problem you're having? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. My solution is pass Media object in bean class's constructor and create another method in bean class that will retrieve media information and update bean object. This method is called through constructor. Now add this bean class's object in ObservableList. Observable list get updated automatically when media information event is fired. Now i can render tableview using ObservableList and using table.refresh() method, i can refresh table data when event is fired.